# include angular in jasmine-node

Tags: node.js, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test an angular module using jasmine-node, my test is setup as

```
var fs = require('fs');
var angular = require('../bower_components/angular/angular')
var fsm = require('../filesystemModel');
describe("get files",function(){
    it("should get files from the file system",function(){
        console.log(fsm);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this fails to load angular, and therefore, the filesystemModel breaks because angular is undefined. I think this is because angular is looking for `window` and `document`, which I don't think are provided in jasmine-node.

I know node-webkit talks about using chromedriver for testing, but I'm trying to be consistent with tests for modules, some of which are available outside of node-webkit, some which require node-webkit.

Any suggestions on getting jasmine-node testing with node-webkit? Or node testing with karma is another option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) which runs the tests in real browsers.